# Android checkbox issue in custom list item view

Tags: android, android-widget

Please forgive me for what may sound like a newbie question as I am just getting started
with Android.

What I am attempting to accomplish is creating a custom list Item layout that contains 2 textViews and a checkbox for selecting multiple items. The problem is the checkboxes are
"extra" selecting list items, (example) if I select #1 then #9 and # 18 selects as well.
as if the checkBox instances are recycling themselves or maybe sharing the same listener IDs
if that even makes sense. Ive narrowed my code to the primary components for simplicity. Any suggestions would be dearly appreciated.

```
package com.untame.mobile.app;

import java.text.ChoiceFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.untame.mobile.app.*;

public class TestList extends ListActivity {


ArrayList<Map<String, String>> artistList;
private static String TAG = "TESTLIST!";
ListView listv;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.testlayout);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    artistList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();


    for(Integer loop = 0 ;loop < 21;loop++){
        String loopI = loop.toString();
        Map<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("artist", loopI);
        hm.put("count", loopI);
        artistList.add(hm);
    }

     // Loading artistNames in Background Thread
   // new LoadArtistList().execute("extra_tracks");
    listv = (ListView) getListView();
    listv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
   // listv.setItemsCanFocus(false);


 final class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


 ArrayList<Integer> ids;
public MyListAdapter(Context context) {


    ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.testlistitem1, null, false);
        convertView.setClickable(true);

        holder = new ViewHolder(getApplicationContext());

        holder.choose = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.testcheckBox1);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }





    return convertView;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return artistList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return artistList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
         MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this);
         setListAdapter(adapter);







        }

}
```

ViewHolder.java

```
package com.untame.mobile.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewHolder extends View {
    public ViewHolder(Context context) {
    super(context);

}
    public CheckBox remove;
    public CheckBox choose;
    public TextView text2;
    public TextView text1;

}
```

testlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

testitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <com.untame.mobile.app.ArtistListCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/testcheckBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="choose"
         />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: arise same problem today :( tried many thing but still dont get any solution . tell me if u solved it ..

Answer (score 1):

Solved!!! It appears after much trial and error, that one must store the actual checkbox information (ie : checkbox.isChecked) into a seperate object that can be stored as a tag inside the current checkbox. This way when the view redraws the new items as you scroll the
list the newly created checkbox can recapture its last state from the object it was stored in.

In my case, I have a list of Music Artists in the list so I created an Artist.java class
to create Artist objects to store as checkbox tags.